# Fixed number of threads on OMATPE

Tags: netty

We are using netty 3.6.5 and have been using an ExecutionHandler coupled with OMATPE on our channel pipeline. Our current requirements are to scale to as many threads as possible with events processed in the order they are received. Application or per channel memory are not yet a constraint and we disabled by setting these to 0 in OMATPE.

After some playing around with netty code, we found that OMATPE uses a fixed number of threads at startup and the number remains same although there is variation in the number of connections received by server. We found the following issues with OMATPE:
1. allowCoreThreadTimeOut - This feature is to reduce the number of core threads when there are lesser number of requests. We are noticing quite a lot of threads getting created and destroyed when processing requests. However, the total number of threads always remains at core pool count during any snapshot. This is not a major issue for us. We call setAllowCoreThreadTimeout(false) to disable core threads timing out and we are trying to start with low thread count. However the number of threads never goes above the low thread count even when setMaximumPoolSize is called due to next problem.
2. Unbounded LinkedBlockingQueue: OMATPE uses LinkedBlockingQueue with unlimited capacity and because of this no new threads get added when number of requests to server increases. This is causing latencies on the queued requests and we would like to avoid queuing unless we are short of processing resources.

We were wondering if you have any other alternate suggestions or solutions for our requirements of ordered channel events and scalable threads based on load. Also, let me know if you need any other details regarding the setup.